# Functional immutable way in javascript to copy an array with additional items in certain positions depending on condition on items

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, immutability

I have an array:

```
[
    { "name": "batman", "hasSidekick": true },
    { "name": "shazam!", "hasSidekick": false },
    { "name": "capt america", "hasSidekick": true },
    { "name": "spiderman", "hasSidekick": false }
]
```

From this, I want to create a new array of hero names which will have all of the above names but when `hasSidekick` is true for a hero, there should be an additional name inserted after it.

Expected output:

```
[
    "batman",
    "batman's sidekick",
    "shazam!", ,
    "capt america",
    "capt america's sidekick",
    "spiderman"
]
```

I can do it with `forEach` and pushing additional items conditionally based on `hasSidekick`:

```
const heroes = [
  { name: "batman", hasSidekick: true },
  { name: "shazam!", hasSidekick: false },
  { name: "capt america", hasSidekick: true },
  { name: "spiderman", hasSidekick: false },
];
let heroesAndSidekicks = [];
heroes.forEach(hero => {
  heroesAndSidekicks.push(hero.name);
  if (hero.hasSidekick) {
    heroesAndSidekicks.push(`${hero.name}'s sidekick`);
  }
});
console.log(heroesAndSidekicks);
```

But please suggest how I can do it in functional programming way without mutation.

Comment: You can do it with `Array.prototype.reduce`.

Comment: what do you mean "without mutation"? I'm just confused why you need that?

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.concat` to combine the results from each iteration. The results from each iteration should be an array with 1 element or 2 elements, depending on whether the hero has a sidekick.

Comment: Wouldn't you need at least some mutation if you want **add** items to your array? There is no adding or removing without changing something. Or do you mean without mutating the original array?

Comment: I am also confused by the "without mutation" requirement. You want to create a new array right? Well that new array is going to start out empty and in order to get elements into it you are going to have to "mutate" it.

Comment: @Barmar, I thought I had already shared how I did it in the last paragraph. Anyway, I have posted my code.

Comment: That code uses mutation, you said you want to do it without mutation. Show your attempt at that.

Comment: By without mutation I mean to follow the functional programming approach - data object should not be changed after it is created. In my example I mutate the `heroesAndSidekicks` array after it is created by using Array.prototype.push().

Comment: I understand what you mean. I'm just trying to get you to try to do that yourself, so we don't do your work for you. I even gave you hints that should get you going in the right direction. If you can't get it working, we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @sompnd, I still don't understand why you through off the word "mutation" in the question? And it's concept is separate with with the concept of functional programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

```js
var data = [{ name: "batman", hasSidekick: true }, { name: "shazam!", hasSidekick: false }, { name: "capt america", hasSidekick: true }, { name: "spiderman", hasSidekick: false }],
    result = data.flatMap(({ name, hasSidekick }) => hasSidekick
        ? [name, name + '\'s sidekick']
        : name
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! The flatmap will flatten out if an array is returned. This is fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

I think [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) can solve your issue. From the documentation:

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

Please find a possible solution below:

```js
const data = [
    { "name": "batman", "hasSidekick": true },
    { "name": "shazam!", "hasSidekick": false },
    { "name": "capt america", "hasSidekick": true },
    { "name": "spiderman", "hasSidekick": false }
];

const result = data.reduce((a, e) => {
  a.push(e.name);

  if (e.hasSidekick) {
     a.push(`${e.name}'s sidekick`);
  }

  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: `a.push()` is mutation.